# Manage the version of a single file separatly from the rest of my project

Tags: git

I've used git for some days but only basic commands.

In my project, I have a file which has some versions and which I often commit.
I would like to can handle the version file in my project.

ie, come back to an old version of this file in a previous commit without change the other files. (in the commits, I add/change only this file)

Then, I'll be able to launch the latest version of my project with different versions of this file.

I had thought to create a branch each version, and to merge (actually, replace) the file of my branch with my master branch.
But a branch take every files of the project, not just one file...

To resume : I would like to manage the version of a file separatly from main project (master).

How to can I do ?

Thank you.

[image: Example]

**EDIT :**

I know how to merge/replace one file of a branch into master.

I'm going to be more clearly :
**I'm looking for how to create a branch with only one file from the project.**

**EDIT 2 :**

Maybe: Create a branch and remove every files except the interesting one in the branch.

Then, `git merge mybranch` and it's good, there is only my single file which will be merged.
=> it's not a good idea, cause the merge will overwrite (actually remove) every files which are not in the branch.

`git checkout mybranch myfile` is the single solution.

Comment: Sounds like cherry picking or checking out individual files.

Comment: Yes, I know how to merge just one file of a branch but I'm afraid to merge every files by accident.
Maybe, there isn't easy way to do what I want. Other than just merge one file into master.

Comment: Assuming I understand you correctly, I recommend looking into `git subtree` or `git subhistory`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this? Knowing that would make it much easier to understand what you're trying to ask.

Comment: @Ajedi32 : Ok I've seen this but it needs to have the single file into a folder.  I've edited my post.

Comment: If you are worried about messing things up accidentally, try creating a branch from the branch you intend to work on just to use for practice.  Then once you succeed there, maybe you'll feel ready to do it to your real branch.

Comment: In response to edit 2, it wouldn't work that way. Merging the branch would result in all the changes from the merged branch being applied. That includes the change were you removed everything except the single file you're interested in.

Comment: Wow, I didn't think to that ... I thought that I have to do a `git reset --hard` to remove files not followed. I'm going to try every ways explained here with a fake repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The git command you want is

```
git checkout [<commit>] [<path-to-file>]
```

Use git log to find the name of the commit you want to change the file to.

Comment: Basically every branch has every file. Your best bet is probably to create a new branch off master, check out the version of the other file you want using this command and check it in. That way you get the overall combination you want without running the risk of affecting master. Otherwise you'll have to add your file to a separate repository and manage the link between the two.